# Finding a 'spike' or drop in a dataset programatically

Tags: python, statistics

If I have a dataset that looks like this

```
[0.523,0.445,0.558,0.492,0.440,0.502,0.742,0.802,0.821,0.811,0.804,0.860]
```

As you can see, there is a 'spike' in the values after 0.502. Is there a way to find this programmatically in Python? 
I'm already using Numpy and Scipy; I'm sure those libraries contain something like this. I just don't know what this procedure is called.

An added bonus would be to adjust the 'sensitivity' of detecting a spike or drop, since the dataset can be quite noise. A spike would mean a sustained increase in the moving averages of the values, and a drop would mean a sustained decrease values.

The range of each value is [-1,1]. The number of values in the array would be 50-100.

Comment: Does the data represent a `spike` after the 0,0502 reading (index 6 onwards) ? I would suggest that a spike is characterised by a momentary increased, followed quickly by a decrease. In your data-set there is an increase over two data items, which is then not followed by a decrease. To me that isn't a spike, but it might well be a rising edge of an increase, which is something different.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the diff function of numpy:

```
import numpy    
a = [0.523,0.445,0.558,0.492,0.440,0.502,0.742,0.802,0.821,0.811,0.804,0.860]
numpy.diff(a)
```

This would give you:

```
array([-0.078,  0.113, -0.066, -0.052,  0.062,  0.24 ,  0.06 ,  0.019,
       -0.01 , -0.007,  0.056])
```

If the number is positive, then it's a jump up, if it's negative, then it's a jump down.

If you just want to find where there are spikes, up or down try this:

```
abs(numpy.diff(a)) > 0.2
```

Adjusting the 0.2 up or down would make it less or more sensitive, respectively. This would give:

```
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. This would tell me even if there's a momentary increase in the values; I'm looking for a *sustained* increase in the values.

Comment: You'll want to use a moving average or a low-pass filter on your data before you run this diff. This will reduce momentary jumps and allow you to find more sustained trends.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple to find where the difference of two adjacent values in a sequence differs by a threshold:

```
def findSpikes(data, threshold=0.2):
    prev = None
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        if prev is None:
            prev = v
            continue

        delta = abs(v - prev)
        if delta >= threshold:
            print("Found spike at index %d (value %f)" % (i, v))

        prev = v
```

For your sample data, it will print:

```
Found spike at index 6 (value 0.742000)
```

It's easy to convert the function to a generator; change the `print` line to `yield i, v` or something similar.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. This would tell me even if there's a momentary increase in the values; I'm looking for a *sustained* increase in the values.