# Detection of regime change in time series

Tags: python

I would like to detect a time series regime change (or anomaly).
By regime change, I mean that the linear trend is changed / broken (see plot below).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(50)
y = [1.28, 1.28, 1.26, 1.32, 1.34, 1.33, 1.38, 1.39, 1.37, 1.42, 
1.42, 1.41, 1.39, 1.41, 1.45, 1.45, 1.46, 1.5, 1.49, 1.53, 1.53, 
1.54, 1.61, 1.59, 1.62, 1.66, 1.63, 1.66, 1.66, 1.7, 1.76, 1.84, 
1.88, 1.97, 1.94, 1.98, 2.01, 2.02, 0.73, 0.72, 0.76, 0.87, 0.97, 
1.01, 0.98, 1.16, 1.22, 1.3, 1.27, 1.33]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]
I have been searching for a while but cannot find a way to detect the big change in this time series.

Detecting a diff is not enough for me because I need to be able to detect that the rough linear trend is changed. The data can have a diff from one observation to the next that is large but the trend (linear trend) is still correct.

**To explain why I abandoned the diff method:**

The observation in x-axis around 45-46 shows a jump in the value but is actually in the linear trend, therefore not a "regime change" for me. This is exactly why I abandoned the diff method and I am looking for a "trend" method.
I have been thinking of looping on observations, fit a linear regression and predict the next point, calculate an error, etc. But I would rather use a library made for this if it exists.

Comment: Define "regime change".  And what do you want to do with the result of this "detection"?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366142/finding-very-large-jumps-in-data) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632205/finding-a-spike-or-drop-in-a-dataset-programatically)

Comment: Look at the first answer in the marked duplicate using `np.diff()`

Comment: @Sheldore I had a look at similar solutions as the diff but that does not answer my problem. I have added some comment.

Comment: @tucson Then please show an example where plain difference (absolute value thereof) does not suffice.

Comment: @dedObed Actually the observation in x-axis around 45-46 shows a jump in the value, which would trigger a rather large difference, but is actually in the linear trend, therefore not a "regime change" for me. This is exactly why I abandoned the diff method and I am looking for a "trend" method.

Comment: @tucson See my answer. If doesn't fit your need, I'll need the tough example, this one is way too easy ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me plot differences (orange) and second order (green) of your data:

[image: Data, differences and second-order differences]

As far as I can see, both of these seem rather discriminative towards detection of the jump, in this case a simple thresholding would do as a classifier.

**The second order difference** should be especially indicative of jump given how you describe the task: for a linear change, it **'s bound to be (around) zero** for non-jumpy sections.

Full code to reproduce the plot:

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                                                                              


x = range(50)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
y = [1.28, 1.28, 1.26, 1.32, 1.34, 1.33, 1.38, 1.39, 1.37, 1.42,                                                                                                                                                                             
1.42, 1.41, 1.39, 1.41, 1.45, 1.45, 1.46, 1.5, 1.49, 1.53, 1.53,                                                                                                                                                                             
1.54, 1.61, 1.59, 1.62, 1.66, 1.63, 1.66, 1.66, 1.7, 1.76, 1.84,                                                                                                                                                                             
1.88, 1.97, 1.94, 1.98, 2.01, 2.02, 0.73, 0.72, 0.76, 0.87, 0.97,                                                                                                                                                                            
1.01, 0.98, 1.16, 1.22, 1.3, 1.27, 1.33]                                                                                                                                                                                                     


def get_deltas(series):                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    return [series[i+1] - series[i] for i in range(len(series)-1)]                                                                                                                                                                           


y_delta = get_deltas(y)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
y_delta_delta = get_deltas(y_delta)                                                                                                                                                                                                          

plt.scatter(x, y)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
plt.scatter(x[:-1], y_delta)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
plt.scatter(x[:-2], y_delta_delta)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
plt.show()
```